# error in deleting a node from singly linked circular linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am having some trouble in deleting a node fro a circular linked list specifically deleting the head node.I tried to debug the code and problem that i found out was that the head node is not getting updated after deletion.that means if my list is 1->2->3->1(the 1 at the end here is actually the repetition of head node 1 to show circular link list ) and after trying to delete '1' the list becomes 1->2->3->2...So basically the the head node is not getting updated and hence when I try to print this linked list it enters infinite loop as the head node is encountered only once and the stopping condition is nover met again. below is the code which I have written for deletion

```
public class cirlinklist {

private int data;
private cirlinklist next;
private cirlinklist head;

public cirlinklist()
    {
    data = 0;
    next = this;
    }

public cirlinklist(int val) 
    {
    data = val;
    next = this;
    }

public void cirlist(int val)
    {
    cirlinklist node = new cirlinklist(val);

    if(this.next == this)                         //only one node present
        {
        node.next = this;
        this.next = node;
        }

    else
        {

        cirlinklist temp = this.next;
        //cirlinklist head = this;
        /*while(node != head)
            node = node.next;*/
        node.next = temp.next;                    //adding after the last added node.For adding before last added node change to temp here and temp.next in next line    
        this.next.next = node;
        }

    }

public void printlist()
    {
    //cirlinklist head = this;                             //start node
    cirlinklist node = this;                             //node for traversing and printing
    System.out.println("Circular Link list data is:");

    do
        {
        System.out.println(node.data);
        node = node.next;
        }
    while(node != head);
    System.out.println(node.data);
    }

public void check()
    {

    }

public cirlinklist delete(int val)
    {
    head = this;
    cirlinklist node = head;
    cirlinklist node2 = node;
    if(head.data == val)                   //if the node to be deleted is head node
        {
        //this = this.next;
        while(node.next != head)          //iterate till the last node i.e. the node which is pointing to head
            {
            node = node.next;
            }
        node.next = node.next.next;       // update current node pointer to next node of head

        //node = node.next;

        head = head.next;                //update head node

        /*this.next = head.next.next;
        this.data = head.next.data;*/

        return this;
        }
    else                                // if node to be deleted is other than head node
        {
        while(node.data != val)        // find the node
            {
            node = node.next;
            node2.next = node;
            }
        node2.next = node.next; //updating next field of previous node to next of current node.current node deleted
        node = null;
        return this;
        }
    }

public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    cirlinklist obj = new cirlinklist(1);
    cirlinklist obj2 = new cirlinklist();
    //obj.cirlist(1);
    obj.cirlist(2);
    obj.cirlist(3);

    obj.printlist();
    obj2 = obj.delete(1);
    System.out.println("Circular list after deletion is");
    obj2.printlist();
    }
}
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: In the example you gave us, if I want to remove '1', it should remove the first and the last one?

Comment: @HugoSousa the '1' node at the end is actually the head node only.since it is circular link list so I repeated '1'.there is actually only one '1' which is the head node

Comment: Note that it would be easier to debug if we could see the rest of the code, since you're doing everything with void functions and no visible use of global data.

Comment: @RyanJ I have made changes in the above post.I have posted full code with some more modification but still same infinite loop problem

Answer (score 0):

```
if(head.data == val)                   //if the node to be deleted is head node
    {
    //this = this.next;
    while(node.next != head)          //iterate till the last node i.e. the node which is pointing to head
        {
        node = node.next;
        }
    node.next = node.next.next;      // update current node pointer to next node of head
    //node = node.next;
    head = head.next;                //update head node
    }
```

In this code, where is the head pointing to after

```
node.next = node.next.next ?
```

may be the problem lies there.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code has changed quite a bit since this answer was posted, I am starting fresh. I can solve your problem as it exists currently, but you do have some issues with your list design that I will mention and suggest you redesign what you have.

First, your print function is breaking because you don't have anything that sets `head`, which you are using to determine when to keep printing.

Modify your constructors to:

```
public cirlinklist()
{
    data = 0;
    next = this;
    head = this;
}

public cirlinklist(int val)
{
    data = val;
    next = this;
    head = this;
}
```

Second, your delete function needs to return `head` since that's what you're modifying in that function.

I've posted the cleaner function here:

```
public cirlinklist delete(int val)
{

    cirlinklist node = head;


    if(head.data == val)                   //if the node to be deleted is head node
    {
        //this = this.next;
        while(node.next != head)          //iterate till the last node i.e. the node which is pointing to head
        {
            node = node.next;
        }
        node.next = node.next.next;       // update current node pointer to next node of head

        //node = node.next;

        head = head.next;                //update head node

    /*this.next = head.next.next;
    this.data = head.next.data;*/

        return this;
    }
    else                                // if node to be deleted is other than head node
    {
        cirlinklist prev = node;               // track previous node from current (node)
        while(node.data != val)        // find the node
        {
            prev = node;
            node = node.next;
        }
        prev.next = node.next; //updating next field of previous node to next of current node.current node deleted
        return head;
    }
}
```

This should get you what you want.

However, there is a problem that you're not yet seeing, in that if you try to return `head` and then hope it's a copy of the list, it's not. You're actually modifying the head list and then distributing it to some other method when it returns, meaning that `cirlist obj2 = obj.delete(1);` is not going to give you a new copy of the deleted list, leaving `obj` untouched. You can see this if you add another delete operation after this one and print.

That being said, I modified the function to react properly when deleting a node in the middle.

One other thing you might also want to test for, is removing the tail node, as you might experience problems with that case too.

The last thing I would suggest is you redefine your data structures. You're using the identifier `node` in this case to represent a list node, when in fact, as you've got them defined, are actually lists themselves. A linked-list as is typically defined, is a bunch of nodes linked together, the entire collection being the list.

If you create a data structure to represent the `node`, that is, it's an object that has a data element, and a pointer to the next node, your list can be in a different class entirely and you can operate on the nodes while preserving only a single copy of the list, that you can control and copy with greater ease.

Something like this:

```
public class ListNode {
    public int data;
    public ListNode next = null;

    public ListNode() {
       data = 0;
    }

    public ListNode(int data) {
       this.data = data;
    }

    public ListNode(ListNode node) {
       if ( node != null) {
          this.data = node.data;
          this.next = node.next;
       }
    }
}
```

Then you can have another class that actually provides the operations

```
public class CircularLinkedList {
    public ListNode head;

    public CircularLinkedList(...) {}

    public void addToList(int data) {}
    public void deleteFromList(int data) {}

    ... // and so-on
}
```

The `head` in this case, is your list, and any time you make changes or need to manipulate it, you can define functions that will do so in terms of `head` and then act appropriately.

Good luck to you

Comment: I tried to do this way also but still not able to resolve the issue.I have posted my full code above with your suggestions also in them(commented out for now but I tried them) but still same infinite loop problem occurs